# See if a braintree transaction has a successful status

Tags: payment, braintree

Braintree provides a [pretty massive list of different statuses](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/statuses) to a transaction. Without hardcoding a massive list of statuses (that might change in the future), is there a recommended way to know if a [`Braintree::Transaction`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/ruby) is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following response from Braintree support:

> A successful transaction will go through the following statuses: Authorized > Submitted for Settlement > Settling > Settled.  If you're aiming to only show successful transactions my recommendation would be to only pull transactions with a status of Settled.  Once a transaction has reached the Settled status it will never change. However, transactions with a status of Submitted for Settlement or Settling, while rare, could potentially be declined or return an error during the settlement process.

In my code I chose to do the following:

```
def is_braintree_status_successful?(braintree_transaction)
  %w(authorized submitted_for_settlement settling settled).include?(braintree_transaction.status)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I also asked a similar question to Braintree support, and the answer may be useful for others, even if I decided to go with Stripe (I found stripe much better after all my tests ;).

**Question**

Hi,

Just integrating Braintree, but can’t find how I’m supposed to get a transaction confirmation (meaning it has correctly been ‘charged’). When I create a ‘transaction.sale’ (including submitForSettlement) I always get (sandbox) a response indicating the status ‘Submitted for settlement’, and the transaction doesn't go to settled until Braintree globally process it (at night, etc.). I also can’t find a related webhook to get payment confirmation (as I currently get using PayPal - IPN).

When/how can I get a payment confirmation so I can then ‘deliver’ the purchased item? By checking your docs, it’s like you can’t get a confirmation until the next day… how does it work exactly?

Thank you!

**Answer**

Hi Nacho,

Thanks for reaching out!

A Braintree transaction goes through several steps, the second of which is submitted for settlement. This means that the money has begun to move from the customers account, and is the immediate state of a transaction after being submitted; it's not possible to get an immediate 'settled' or 'complete' status on submission. Transactions in this state will generally move to settling, then settled, within 24 hours, although it can depend on your processing bank.

It is very unusual for a transaction to fail when moving from submitted for settlement to settled, as the amount will have been authorised prior to submission for settlement. Authorising a transaction means the funds are put on hold within the customers account, for a certain timeframe depending on payment method, until they are settled. We get an immediate response from the processing bank as to whether an authorisation is successful, which you'll see in the Braintree_Transaction response object.

As such, you can generally rely on the status of submitted for settlement to reflect a valid, successful transaction.

We don't offer webhooks for transactions - instead, our API is designed to give instant feedback via the response object. Because of this, we only provide webhooks for asynchronous events that aren't triggered by an API call (such as billing a subscription or disbursing funds). We encourage our customers to avail of our API responses, in addition to our reporting system and comprehensive search call options, for any extra functionality they require.

If you wanted to pull updated statuses for transactions, such as to confirm a payment has settled, you could use the Transaction.find() API request, pass in the transaction ID and read in the status from the response object. This could easily be run as a script that iterates through the previous days transaction IDs and updates the status of each on a daily basis.

I hope this explains the transaction process with more clarity and offers you some options!

Kind regards, Braintree

Just in case it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they have a method on the result object called [is_success](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/python#successful-result), which will return a True if successful, False if not.

Comment: This is incorrect for my case since I get a subscription, and check the list of transactions and want to know which ones were "successful" (or on a successful journey).

Answer (score 0):

When you make a transaction, you should be given back a result object that will contain whether the transaction was successful or not.

Here is a contrived example

```
<?php

require 'braintree_setup.php';

$nonceFromTheClient = $_POST["payment-method-nonce"];

$result = Braintree\Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => '10.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonceFromTheClient,
    'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => true,
        'threeDSecure' => [
            'required' => true
        ]
    ]

]);

if ($result->success) {
   die('Payment was successful');
}
```

Edit: Regarding your comment,

If you'd like to get a collection of transactions, you'll need to use the `Braintree\Transaction::search()` method.

Once that is done, you can then loop over the results as you would with anything else.

```
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    var_dump($transaction);
}
```